# Iterated expectation over different sets of variables

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation

For some random variables $Y, X, Z,$ and $Q$, can we simplify $E[E[Y|X,Z]|Z,Q]$? Is it correct that $E[E[Y|X,Z]|Z,Q] = E[Y|X,Q]$ (idea being that $Z$ is averaged out)?

In general, for some sets of variables $A$ and $B$, such that $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$ and $A \not \subseteq B$ and $B \not \subseteq A$, what is $E[E[Y|A]|B]$ equal to?

Answer (score 0):

No, because $Z$ is given in both the inner and outer expectations, it can come out of both. But, $E[Y|X,Q]$ is not a function of $Z$. For your second question, I couldn't make sense $A\cap B$ for random variables $A$ and $B$ (instead of events).

Comment: Thanks. The answer for the first part (first two questions) I understand. For the second part (my third question), $A$ and $B$ are sets of random variables, not random variables. For instance, in the first question $A=\{X, Z \}$ and $B = \{Z, Q\}$

Comment: I see, I'm afraid you can't generalise it to anything. For a simple counter-ex, let $A\cap B$ be a constant RV which will leave the expression as it is.